# In App Insights how to assign text labels to the X-axis values?

Tags: azure-application-insights, kql

Consider the following query:

```
...
| project minutes, agentCount, maxDOP
| summarize round(avg(minutes)) by agentCount, maxDOP
| order by avg_minutes asc
| project rn=row_number(), avg_minutes, strcat('A', agentCount, 'x', maxDOP, 'M')
| render columnchart
```

This produces the following graph:
[image]

The problem is that the labels down below are sorted lexicographically, which does not correspond to the actual order by `avg_minutes`. I would like to have these text labels instead of the row numbers on the graph, but I cannot figure out how to do it.

Displaying them inside the bars (turned vertically, of course) is also a solution, if possible. Anything that would make clear which label corresponds to which bar would be much better than the current display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Column chart is a type of categorical charts allow users to represent a dimension or column on the X-axis of a chart, this is especially useful in histograms.

Coming to your problem -

> I would like to have these text labels instead of the row numbers on the graph, but I cannot figure out how to do it.

You can achieve it simply by removing the row number from the project line of the query, as shown below.

```
...
| project minutes, agentCount, maxDOP
| summarize round(avg(minutes)) by agentCount, maxDOP
| order by avg_minutes asc
| project strcat('A', agentCount, 'x', maxDOP, 'M'), avg_minutes
| render columnchart
```

I tried something similar with sample data in Azure Data Explorer as and achieved the desired result as shown in the picture below.

[image: KQL]

I would suggest to read [Use Kusto queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/tutorial?pivots=azuredataexplorer#display-a-chart-or-table-render) document from Microsoft and [Chart visualizations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/visualize/workbooks-chart-visualizations) document for more information.